# unwraping div tags between two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to remove the div's between two specific elements

```html
<div id="test1">
  <div id="test2">
    <div id="test3">
      <div id="test4">
        <div id="test5">
          <div id="test6">
            <ul id="ulid">
              <li>item1</li>
              <li>item2</li>
              <li>item3</li>
              <li>item4</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i want to remove the div's between  id test1 and id ulid
how to use unwrap here
expected output

```
<div id="test1">
  <ul id="ulid">
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
    <li>item4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The question is unclear, i do not see any div with id test

Comment: sorry its test1 @brk

Comment: 1. `i want to remove the div's between ul`-> no `div` there inside `ul`. 2. `and div with id test`->unable to see `test` id, it's like test1,2,3.. so you want to remove all? Please clarify your question and add your effort too. As well as what expected outcome you want.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. Show us what you tried. The objective here is for us to help you fix **your code** when it doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 1):

```js
$( "#test2" ).replaceWith($('#ulid'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="test1">
      <div id="test2">
        <div id="test3">
          <div id="test4">
            <div id="test5">
              <div id="test6">
                <ul id="ulid">
                  <li>item1</li>
                  <li>item2</li>
                  <li>item3</li>
                  <li>item4</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: removes the `<ul>` too ... no need for `.contents()`

Comment: use clone() instead of contents() $( "#test2" ).replaceWith($('#ulid').clone());

Comment: Don't even need the clone ... should work simply as `$( "#test2" ).replaceWith($('#ulid'))`

Comment: Not only the cleanest code solution but probably the most efficient too vs the `unwrap()` approaches

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a loop for this. You are missing the `contents` function in jQuery.

It returns the child elements of the selected element.

```
$('div[id^="test"][id!="test1"]').contents().unwrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and add this jQuery `$('div[id^="test"][id!="test1"]').contents().unwrap();`

```js
$('div[id^="test"][id!="test1"]').contents().unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test1">
  <div id="test2">
    <div id="test3">
      <div id="test4">
        <div id="test5">
          <div id="test6">
            <ul id="ulid">
              <li>item1</li>
              <li>item2</li>
              <li>item3</li>
              <li>item4</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are unwrapping `div` elements which are parent elements of `ul#ulid`.

You can just call `unwrap()` on `#ulid` multiple times until you reach the element you want to keep (i.e., `#test1`). You can check if you have reached the element using `attr()`. This is easy because the objective is to remove every parent until `#test1` is the parent. There is an extremely useful `parent()` function implemented in jQuery.

Here's a simple snippet that demonstrates this. (I'm using CSS to show that the elements are being removed.)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#unwrap").click(function() {
    while ($("#ulid").parent().attr("id") !== "test1") { // while the id of the parent is not "test1"
      $("#ulid").unwrap();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#test1 {
  color: red;
}

#test2 {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test1">
  <div id="test2">
    <div id="test3">
      <div id="test4">
        <div id="test5">
          <div id="test6">
            <ul id="ulid">
              <li>item1</li>
              <li>item2</li>
              <li>item3</li>
              <li>item4</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="unwrap">Unwrap</button>
```

Here's what the HTML looks like after it has been unwrapped:

```
<div id="test1">
  <ul id="ulid">
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
    <li>item4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And your problem is (hopefully) solved!

All that you really required was a simple loop. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, why is this downvoted? Is it unsafe? I achieved what the OP asked for.

Comment: Personally I thought this was a creative solution